# Apache Nifi PutSQL Processor Connection to Oracle

Tags: apache-nifi

Hi I have a oracle database and I have a putsql processor to write data to it.My problem is after a while my putsql locked out and start to type this error.I terminate all waiting process in the queue ,it seems working but after a while it crash.I try to stop start nifi,renenter credentials etc...but doesnt solved issue.

2021-01-25 15:58:12,224 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=07de5e99-900f-385f-ff39-3e4bab18cb79] org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL$$Lambda$606/1336686058@498d2c5e failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to commit database connection due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection; rolling back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to commit database connection due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to commit database connection due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$constructProcess$16(PutSQL.java:555)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.Put.onTrigger(Put.java:122)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$onTrigger$20(PutSQL.java:600)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.onTrigger(PutSQL.java:600)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:205)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:2254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2357)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2407)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:358)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:358)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$constructProcess$16(PutSQL.java:552)
... 15 common frames omitted
2021-01-25 15:58:12,225 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-3] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=07de5e99-900f-385f-ff39-3e4bab18cb79] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to commit database connection due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to commit database connection due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to commit database connection due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$constructProcess$16(PutSQL.java:555)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.Put.onTrigger(Put.java:122)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$onTrigger$20(PutSQL.java:600)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.onTrigger(PutSQL.java:600)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:205)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getAutoCommit(PhysicalConnection.java:2254)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2357)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2407)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:358)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:358)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$constructProcess$16(PutSQL.java:552)
... 15 common frames omitted
2021-01-25 15:58:13,138 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=07de5e99-900f-385f-ff39-3e4bab18cb79] Failed to update database due to a failed batch update, java.sql.BatchUpdateException: IO Error: Checksum fail. There were a total of 73 FlowFiles that failed, 0 that succeeded, and 0 that were not execute and will be routed to retry; : java.sql.BatchUpdateException: IO Error: Checksum fail
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: IO Error: Checksum fail
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:12296)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:246)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:223)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:223)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$null$10(PutSQL.java:390)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:127)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$new$12(PutSQL.java:388)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PutGroup.putFlowFiles(PutGroup.java:94)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.Put.onTrigger(Put.java:102)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$onTrigger$20(PutSQL.java:600)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.onTrigger(PutSQL.java:600)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:205)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.needLine(PhysicalConnection.java:4220)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.closeOrCache(OracleStatement.java:1431)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.close(OracleStatement.java:1410)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.close(OracleStatementWrapper.java:102)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.close(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:82)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.close(DelegatingStatement.java:149)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.close(DelegatingStatement.java:149)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL.lambda$null$10(PutSQL.java:392)
... 18 common frames omitted
2021-01-25 15:58:13,138 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=07de5e99-900f-385f-ff39-3e4bab18cb79] Failed to rollback database connection due to %s: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
2021-01-25 15:58:13,138 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=07de5e99-900f-385f-ff39-3e4bab18cb79] Failed to reset autocommit due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection:
2021-01-25 15:58:13,139 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=07de5e99-900f-385f-ff39-3e4bab18cb79] org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL$$Lambda$606/1336686058@e0450d6 failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to commit database connection due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection; rolling back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to commit database connection due to java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connectio

Comment: try reducing Batch Size, Concurrent Task and Run Duration